# Why does XBee transmit fail sometimes?

Tags: arduino, xbee

I doing a project with [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) R3 and [XBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee) S2 transmission. I use a couple of sensors like a wireless ([RF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_frequency)) temperature sensor, two SHT75 sensors, a 3-axis accelerometer and an illumination sensor. And after collecting the data, we use XBee (S2, API mode) to send the data to the gateway. Every round is about one second.

1. The first problem is the data is about 16 bytes, but the packet does not send successful every round. Sometime it works, and sometimes it doesn't, but the payload of XBee can be 60 or 70 bytes in the datasheet... But if I put the payload as some simply an integer (like 1, 2, 3), not the data from sensor, and the transmission will be stable.
2. After meeting the problem above, I divided the data into two packets (each with an eight bytes payload), and the first packet is very stable, but the second is very unstable. As mentioned above, if I put some number into the second packets instead of the sensing data the second packet will become stable and send successfully every round.

So I think it's the code problem, but idk where is the problem. I try to change the baud rate or increasing the delay time between the two packets. Where is the problem? The following is my code:

```
#include <XBee.h>
#include <i2cmaster.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <Sensirion.h>
#include "Wire.h"
#include "MMA845XQ.h"

**///////////////////////////// XBee setup //////////////////////////////////**
XBee xbee = XBee();
XBeeAddress64 remoteAddress = XBeeAddress64(0x00000000, 0x00000000);
ZBRxResponse zbRx = ZBRxResponse();
ZBTxStatusResponse zbTxStus = ZBTxStatusResponse();

uint8_t payload[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
uint8_t payload1[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

**///////////////////////////// Accelerometer //////////////////////////////////**
MMA845XQ accel;

**////////////////////////// SHT1 serial data and clock ////////////////////**
const byte dataPin = 2;
const byte sclkPin = 3;
Sensirion sht = Sensirion(dataPin, sclkPin);
unsigned int rawData;
float temperature;
float humidity;
byte stat;

**////////////////////////// SHT2 serial data and clock ////////////////////**
const byte dataPin1 = 4;
const byte sclkPin1 = 5;
Sensirion sht1 = Sensirion(dataPin1, sclkPin1);
unsigned int rawData1;
float temperature1;
float humidity1;
byte stat1;

**//////////////////////////// Illumination sensor ////////////////////////**
int sensorPin = A0;    // Select the input pin for the potentiometer
int sensorValue = 0;   // Variable to store the value coming from the sensor
long int pardata, pardata_low, pardata_hi, real_pardata;
uint16_t illumindata = 0;

void setup () {
    i2c_init(); //Initialise the I²C bus
    PORTC = (1 << PORTC4) | (1 << PORTC5); //Enable pullups
    Wire.begin();
    accel.begin(false, 2);
    Serial.begin(115200);
    xbee.begin(Serial);
}

void loop () {
    payload[0] = 10;
    payload1[0] = 11;

    **/////////////////////RF temperature sensor/////////////////////////////**
    int dev = 0x5A<<1;
    int data_low = 0;
    int data_high = 0;
    int pec = 0;
    i2c_start_wait(dev + I2C_WRITE);
    i2c_write(0x07);
    i2c_rep_start(dev + I2C_READ);
    data_low = i2c_readAck(); //Read 1 byte and then send ack
    data_high = i2c_readAck(); //Read 1 byte and then send ack
    pec = i2c_readNak();
    i2c_stop();

    double tempFactor = 0.02; // 0.02 degrees per LSB (measurement resolution of the MLX90614)
    double tempData = 0x0000; // Zero out the data
    int frac; // Data past the decimal point

    // This masks off the error bit of the high byte, then moves it left 8 bits and adds the low byte.
    tempData = (double)(((data_high & 0x007F) << 8) + data_low);
    tempData = (tempData * tempFactor)-0.01;
    float celcius = tempData - 273.15;
    float fahrenheit = (celcius*1.8) + 32;

    celcius *= 100;
    int a = int(celcius) + 1;
    payload[1] = a >> 8 & 0xff;
    payload[2] = a & 0xff;

    **//////////////////////////// Illumination sensor ////////////////////////////////**
    sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
    TSR(sensorValue);

    payload[3] = pardata_low >> 8 & 0xff;
    payload[4] = pardata_low & 0xff;

    **//////////////////////////// 3-axis accelemeter sensor ////////////////////////////////**
    accel.update();
    payload[5] = accel.getX()*10;
    payload[6] = accel.getY()*10;
    payload[7] = accel.getZ()*10;

    delay(100);

    **////////////////////////////// XBee send first packet///////////////////////////////////////////////**
    xbee = XBee();
    xbee.begin(Serial);
    ZBTxRequest zbTx = ZBTxRequest(remoteAddress, payload, sizeof(payload));
    zbTx.setAddress16(0xfffe);
    xbee.send(zbTx);

    delay(500);

    **//////////////// SHT 1x temperature and humidity sensor /////////////////////////**
    sht.readSR(&stat);                     // Read sensor status register
    sht.writeSR(LOW_RES);                  // Set sensor to low resolution
    sht.readSR(&stat);                     // Read sensor status register again
    sht.measTemp(&rawData);                // sht.meas(TEMP, &rawData, BLOCK)
    sht.meas(TEMP, &rawData, NONBLOCK);
    temperature = sht.calcTemp(rawData);
    sht.measHumi(&rawData);                // sht.meas(HUMI, &rawData, BLOCK)
    humidity = sht.calcHumi(rawData, temperature);
    sht.meas(HUMI, &rawData, NONBLOCK);
    humidity = sht.calcHumi(rawData, temperature);
    temperature *= 100;
    a = int(temperature) + 1;

    payload1[1] = a >> 8 & 0xff;
    payload1[2] = a & 0xff;

    humidity *= 100;
    a = int(humidity) + 1;
    payload1[3] = a >> 8 & 0xff;
    payload1[4] = a & 0xff;

    delay(10);

    sht1.readSR(&stat1);
    sht1.writeSR(LOW_RES);                  // Set sensor to low resolution
    sht1.readSR(&stat1);
    sht1.measTemp(&rawData1);                // sht.meas(TEMP, &rawData, BLOCK)
    temperature1 = sht1.calcTemp(rawData1);
    sht1.measHumi(&rawData1);                // sht.meas(HUMI, &rawData, BLOCK)
    humidity1 = sht1.calcHumi(rawData1, temperature1);

    delay(10);

    temperature1 *= 100;
    a = int(temperature1) + 1;
    payload1[5] = a >> 8 & 0xff;
    payload1[6] = a & 0xff;

    humidity1 *= 100;
    a = int(humidity1) + 1;
    payload1[7] = a >> 8 & 0xff;
    payload1[8] = a & 0xff;

    **////////////////////////////// XBee send second packet ///////////////////////////////////////////////**
    xbee = XBee();
    xbee.begin(Serial);
    zbTx = ZBTxRequest(remoteAddress,payload1, sizeof(payload1));
    zbTx.setAddress16(0xfffe);
    xbee.send(zbTx);
    delay(500);
}

void TSR(int sensorValue)
{
    illumindata = (sensorValue * 4 * 5) / 1.5;
    pardata = 6250/6144*illumindata*10;

    if(pardata > 0)
    {
        if(pardata < 11500)
        {
            real_pardata = 0.0000000020561*pardata*pardata*pardata -
                           0.00002255*pardata*pardata +
                           0.25788*pardata -
                           6.481;
            if (real_pardata < 0)
            {
              real_pardata = 0;
            }

            pardata_hi = real_pardata/65535;
            pardata_low = real_pardata%65535;
        }
        else
        {
            real_pardata = 0.0000049204*pardata*pardata*pardata -
                           0.17114*pardata*pardata +
                           1978.7*pardata -
                           7596900;
            if (real_pardata < 0)
            {
                real_pardata = 0;
            }
            pardata_hi = real_pardata/65535;
            pardata_low = real_pardata%65535;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        pardata_hi = 0;
        pardata_low = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as I am writing this I have solved the same problem you have, though with similar hardware setup. I have used bare avr atxmega128a3u (so no arduino board) and an Xbee S1 communicating on baud rate 115200. After a few days trying to figure this out I came to conclusion, that if your avr is not running at precise clock (external xtal) and you use slightly "faster" baud rate ( >= 115200 ) Xbee's serial hardware has probably trouble recovering clock signal resulting in errors in transmission. (Maybe Xbee has slow bit sampling rate).

Anyway, by ensuring your microprocessor is running at stable clock (you should be safe here 'cause arduino has an external xtal) and by using slower baud rate (try 57600, 19200 or 9600) should solve your problem. I hope so. :)  ...And don't forget to reconfigure Xbee's baud rate in XCTU.

And also it might help if you initliaze xbee only once.Move these lines into setup() function:

```
 setup(){
    // This is changed
    Serial.begin(9600);
    // This is new
    xbee = XBee();
    xbee.begin(Serial);
    // ...
  }
```

EDIT: Also you might be interested in this website where you can see what is the % of error for given clock frequency and baud rate (as well as direct register values to set if you were using bare avr) http://www.wormfood.net/avrbaudcalc.php?postbitrate=9600&postclock=16&hidetables=1